# Sending and receiving mail from/to personal SMTP server

Tags: windows, email, smtp, mail-server

I'm trying to setup a SMTP server from my Windows machine. What I'm trying to do is only for learning experience; I won't actually be using the server regularly. I've installed hMailServer on my Windows 7 computer and I've successfully sent a message from myself (`user@domain.com`) to myself using telnet. I can view the email in a folder in the Program Files installation directory.

Now I want to be able to send email from this server to other email accounts (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) and receive emails sent to `user@domain.com`. Port 25 is not blocked, and I have a domain name pointing to my external IP. When I send an email to my gmail account, somehow it goes back to my email server. And if I send an email from my gmail account, then I don't get it.

Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something? Is there an easier way to configure a personal SMTP server?

Comment: Mail goes back to your server, or it's bounced somewhere? Any server log output?

Answer (score 1):

If its a system on a dynamic ip address, it often gets on [blacklists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) - while its optional, i believe gmail uses a blocklist that inclides them. I've had issues enough with this that running a e mail server on a dynamic IP address dosen't work.

You might want to check your logs to confirm this - you usually get a return message saying that things are blocked.